# Element type is invalid: Expected a string/object got: undefined

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm having a hard time figuring out why I'm getting Input returned `undefined` with this code. The `Button, Card, CardSection` components are being exported/imported the same way.

The rest of the components in the LoginForm render fine if I comment out the `<Input/>` tag.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

`Input.js` -- Not working

```
import React from 'react';
import { Text, TextInput, View } from 'react-native';

const Input = ({ label, value, onChangeText }) => {
    return (
        <View>
            <Text>{label}</Text>
            <TextInput
                value={value}
                onChangeText={onChangeText}
                style={{ height:20, width:100 }}
            />
        </View>
    );
};

export { Input };
```

`Button.js` -- Working

```
const Button = ({ whenPressed, children }) => {

    const { buttonStyle, textStyle } = styles;

    return (
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={whenPressed} style={buttonStyle}>
            <Text style={textStyle}>
                {children}
            </Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        );
};

export { Button };
```

`LoginForm.js`

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View } from 'react-native';
import { Button, Card, CardSection, Input } from './';

class LoginForm extends Component {

    state = { text: '' };

    render() {
        return(
            <Card>
                <CardSection>
                    <Input
                        value={this.state.text}
                        onChangeText={text=> this.setState({ text })}
                    />
                </CardSection>
                <CardSection/>
                <CardSection>
                    <Button style={styles.buttonStyle}>LOGIN</Button>
                </CardSection>
            </Card>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: In the sample code you show the `<Input/>` component in `Index.js` but the `import` in `LoginForm.js` imports `<Input/>` from `./`. Is that how the app imports them too?

Comment: Thanks for making the lightbulb go off. It was returned as `undefined` because it was never exported in the `index.js` file that holds all the exports to App. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

It was returned as `undefined` because it was never exported in the `index.js` file that holds all the exports to App.

In the sample code you show the `<Input/>` component in `Index.js` but the import in `LoginForm.js` imports `<Input/` from `./.`

Comment: That's exactly it. I didn't export it from the `index.js` file as I mentioned above!